# Chrome console output of json has weird behaviour

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, duplicates, output

I have a `json` object with 2 `arrays` where I am removing duplicated elements.
I want to show for testing purpose, the before/after changes.
But an unknown reason my Chrome console output doesn't display all elements of my array even though its length corresponds to the number of elements within the array.

[What I'm expecting vs what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72OID.png)

Created a [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n84hwLor/) if you wanna take a look to the code.

My code is structured as follow :

```
//Before------------------
console.log(myjsonobject);
removeduplicates(myjsonobject);
//After-------------------  
console.log(myjsonobject);
```

Comment: can you just the show the **myjsonobject** too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That behavior is expected as in JavaScript objects are passed as references as oppose to primitives where they are passed as values.

If you perform a deep clone of the array, you'll see that it prints to console just fine..

```
var createdComponents;
createdComponents = {
  "switches":[],
  "SA":[]
};
//Adding duplicates elements to my array
createdComponents.switches.push("SW1");
createdComponents.SA.push("SA1");
createdComponents.switches.push("SW1");
createdComponents.SA.push("SA1");

//Display object with duplicates
console.log("Before:------------");
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(createdComponents)));

//Removing duplicates
createdComponents.switches = removeDuplicates(createdComponents.switches);
createdComponents.SA = removeDuplicates(createdComponents.SA);

//Display new object
console.log("After duplicates being removed:------------");
console.log(createdComponents);

function removeDuplicates(arr){
  let unique_array = []
  for(let i = 0;i < arr.length; i++){
    if(unique_array.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1){
      unique_array.push(arr[i])
    }
  }
  return unique_array
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n84hwLor/2/)